# How to protect files in amazon s3 show files only those authentic user from laravel application

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

Good Day Everybody,

I'm fairly new to AWS, and I have a problem right now.
I'm not even sure if this is something that is possible with Amazon S3.

So my problem is this, I have an laravel application which user upload an images to S3.
I wan't to know how to properly access this images later in the front-end(Some sort of direct link). But at the same time,

I should be able to restrict the users who can access the image. For eg: If user xyz authenticate  that user should be able to see it, not unauthenticated user access.
Authenticate process should be from Laravel application.

Comment: (a) Make sure that your S3 objects are not publically accessible by default (b) have an endpoint on your site that given an image path and name verifies that the user has access to the image (somehow) and then you can either proxy the image download (with [this](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#downloading-files)) or redirect to a [temporary url](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#temporary-urls) (which is an S3 presigned url with limited duration). This is of couse one though, there are probably many other ways